# Reset a JSON array after .slice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm creating a random generator of restaurants. I have a PHP request that get the places in my database then I convert those in a json array.

Then I have a jquery function to display randomly the restaurant with a .slice to delete the place i just had.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 // The "restos" var equals to my full json            
 var restos = <? echo $restos; ?>;

 function getRandomResto(){

        var randomKey = Math.floor(Math.random()*restos.length);
        var resto = restos[randomKey];
        restos.splice(randomKey, 1);

        var title = resto.title;

       //Add content
       $('#place').html('<h2>' + title + '</h2>');

    }
)};
```

This is the short version.

**What I want to do is, when my array is empty, reload it to restart the random display of my restaurant.**

I tried to call again my json var but in the function when restos.length equals 0 but it seems to not be the good solution...

Any help could be really appreciated !

Comment: lenghth() vs length()

Comment: and `length()` vs `length` - property http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp

Comment: To add to what @AllInOne said, `length` is a property, not a method, so no brackets needed.

Comment: @WojciechFrącz Don't recommend w3schools.com as a reference. It's full of errors, see http://w3fools.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clone restos every time, like this:

```
 var restos = <? echo $restos; ?>;
 var currentRestos = restos.slice(0); // this clones an array

 function getRandomResto(){

       if (currentRestos.length == 0) {
         currentRestos = restos.slice(0);
       }

        var randomKey = Math.floor(Math.random()*currentRestos.length);
        var resto = currentRestos[randomKey];
        currentRestos.splice(randomKey, 1);

        var title = resto.title;

       //Add content
       $('#place').html('<h2>' + title + '</h2>');

    }
)};
```